# Netcat only sends answer after I CTRL-C the connection

Tags: linux, debian, netcat

When I run this command `cat index.html | nc -lnvp 2222` and then open the local address of the server in the browser with this header:
`GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.146.131:2222
User-Agent: "my user agent here"
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: de,en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
DNT: 1
Connection: keep-alive`

and this as the index.html: `hi whats up` (thats it)

I get the http request in the terminal where netcat is running and my browser on my other machine is waiting. Only when I CTRL-C the connection on the terminal I get the response in the browser.

My `uname -a` prints out: `Linux kali 4.0.0-kali1-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.0.4-1+kali2 (2015-06-03) x86_64 GNU/Linux`

When I try to use `cat index.html | nc -l 2222` it doesnt work at all. My Kali machine doesnt even get a http request. When I try the same on an Ubuntu machine it works like I want to it to work: It simply sends the index.html to the browser without waiting for me to CTRL-C netcat.

Anyone an idea why netcat behaves so weird?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`man nc` writes:

"netcat stays running until  the  *network*  side  closes" so your browser will wait forever for the data to finish. Use `-q` option to quit, see the man page again: "after  EOF on stdin, wait the specified number of seconds and then quit".

```
cat index.html | nc -lnvp 2222 -q 0
```

`nc -l 2222` does not make sense, you need to use `-p` to specify the port.

Comment: Thank you very much. I should have read the manuel more carefully

Answer (score 5):

There are two different `netcat`s, and you're using one of each:

- Traditional `netcat` will avoid closing the connection by default, because the client might send more data.
- OpenBSD `netcat` closes the connection by default when there's no more data to send.

Old versions of HTTP (like you're falling back on) expects the connection to be closed, so it works by default with the OpenBSD netcat.

You can have traditional `netcat` close the connection on eof as well, using `-q 0`:

```
stuff | nc.traditional -l -p 2222 -q 0
```

Comment: Now with GNU netcat its `-c` to close the connection after EOF in stdin